# Suffix array construction algorithm linear complexity constant

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, suffix-array

A non-recursive linear Suffix Array construction algorithm is presented in this thesis: [Linear-time Suffix Sorting](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/iui.inst.190/Mitarbeiter/baier/gsaca.pdf). The author claims that, overall, the algorithm runs at $O(n)$. While it is well explained, there are only hints that this is case. The implementation of the algorithm [is in this GitHub repository](https://github.com/waYne1337/gsaca/blob/master/gsaca.c) written in C.

My question is: What are the complexity constants (say $O(\alpha n + \beta)$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants) for C code between lines 92 and 186?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants like this are generally not calculated for the run time of algorithms, because it's not clear what they would count - would they count the number of some sort of primitive C operation executed, or the number of x86-64 operations, or the number of arm64 operations, or the microcode operations, or ...?

More frequently than *calculating* the constants, people *measure* the run time and show the $\alpha$ that fits best. They will also sometimes calculate the number of times a specific operation is executed, like comparisons or swaps in a sorting algorithm.